# node import url and querystring types to a TypeScript Application

Tags: node.js, typescript

I would like to import `url` and `querystring` node modules in a TypeScript Application.

```
import url from 'url';
import querystring from 'querystring';
```

But I'm getting the fallowing warning, and I'm not getting typing from it.

> [ts] Could not find a declaration file for module 'url'. '.../node_modules/url/url.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/url` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'url';` [7016]

I know that `url` and `querystring` are node modules. I've Installed `"@types/node": "^10.12.9",` but it does not solves the typing from both neither the warning.

**What Should I Do to get typing from it?**

info: I'ts a frontend application using Vue CLI

here are my `ts.config`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env", "mocha", "chai"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "tests/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "rating-form",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^7.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-slider-component": "^2.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.4",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.9",
    "@types/qs": "^6.5.1",
    "@types/toastr": "^2.1.35",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "^3.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.1.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.20",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you include a triple slash directive which references the `node` types before attempting to import? E.g., `/// <reference types="node"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

In `tsconfig.json`, you have to either add `"node"` to `"types"` array:

```
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env", "mocha", "chai", "node"],
    "paths": {
```

… or remove the array altogether (which is what I would do):

```
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
```